# Rails 4: How to use select_tag such that model and associations are reconstructed automatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model named Parent which looks like this (actual names replaced to protect the innocent):

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children
end
```

... and a model named Child which looks like this:

```
class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent
end
```

In my _form.html.erb used for rendering Child model instances, I have tried to give the user a select list to choose which Parent which they wish to create a new Child for.  (Bonus points:  does this violate some REST principle?  I had considered alternately adding a "create new child" link on the **parent** page which always passes in a specific parent ID, but was not sure that I wouldn't run into this same issue.)

I have rendered the select list thusly, having created an array @allparents in the ChildController's New() method:

```
<%= select_tag "parent_id", options_from_collection_for_select(@allparents, 'id', 'name') %>
```

However, in addition to having to spell out the "parent_id" property name manually in the select_tag declaration, I have to then go and pick the parent _id back out of my params array in the ChildController's Create method as such:

```
def create   @child = Child.new(child_params)   
    @child.parent_id = params[:parent_id]
    # save it 
end
```

Although this works, it feels like a fair bit of "glue" that I'm having to write to manually associate the child to its child.parent_id property, and I get the feeling there must be a better way, but I have been unable to divine the appropriate google fu to figure this out on my own.

One final thought:  The biggest indicator to me that I'm missing something is that when I trigger a strong parameters error, I see that my child model object is being constructed for me, but that the parent_id is a completely separate entity:

**Parameters:**

```
{"utf8"=>"√",
 "authenticity_token"=>"asdefkaheaikehualshalhf",
 "parent_id"=>"2",
 "child"=>{"versionnumber"=>"some user input value"},
 "commit"=>"Create Child"}
```

It seems as though my solution here would be brittle, such that if anyone ever changed the Child's parent_id property name then my view(s) would break.  Does anyone see a better way to go about this? Thank you.

Comment: To put this question in ASP.NET MVC terms, I'm looking for the Rails equivalent of Html.DropDownListFor() which uses static reflection, whereas I feel what I've accomplished in my question's code samples is like an Html.DropDownList().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend having a look at some more online resources like railscast or the rails guides to get a good overview about how to work with forms in rails.

In general it is a good idea to use the `form_for @model do` pattern.

It creates a form-helper where you have an easy mapping of the model fields and the form names.

So in your case it would look like this:

```
= form_for @child do |f|
  = f.collection_select(:parent, Parent.all, :id, :name, :prompt => "Select a Parent")
  = f.submit
```

Comment: I'm inside a form_for tag that the scaffold generator generated for me, but I didn't know form_for had a .collection_select() method.  It'll be worth studying the auto-completion options.  Your answer does result in the automatic reconstruction ("model-binding" in asp.net mvc parlance) of my model.

Comment: there is no such thing as binding or automation in rails. it's all just conventions. if you understand those conventions, most things "just work"